# ProtectedSessionStorage returns empty value even if value exists

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have this extension method:

```
public static async Task<T> GetItemAsync<T>(this ProtectedSessionStorage storage, string name)
{
    var result = await storage.GetAsync<T>(name);
    return result.Success ? result.Value : default;
}
```

And I would call it like this:

```
var value = await sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("MyValue");
```

Nothing special about it. I have situations where the method returns an empty value even though the key exists and it has a value.

Is there a reason why this happens? Maybe due to `async/await`?